# Line break inside a carriage return in a cat function in R

Tags: r, casting, line-breaks, carriage-return

Actually, I want to track some statistics during a computation that takes a lot of time. Here is a reproducible example, even if it doesn't make sense for you, it's easier for me to start from here since I don't want to explain my whole problem and put my whole code. So there is a computation, a while loop that generate random numbers, it is supposed to take a lot of time. During this loop, I want to track some statistics. So I want to track what is the minimum so far, what is the maximum so far, the number of iteration so fart, etc... So it's easy to do it with a cat function. The problem is if I do it the regular way, for each iteration, it adds a new output. See the code :

```
i=1
min=99
max=-99
while(i<10000) {
  x=rnorm( 1, 0, 2 )
  if (x<min)min=x
  if (x>max)max=x
  cat("\niteration :",i)
  cat("\nmin :",min)
  cat("\nmax :",max)
  i=i+1
}
```

console view :

```
  ...
    iteration : 9997
    min : -6.670651
    max : 7.082235
    iteration : 9998
    min : -6.670651
    max : 7.082235
    iteration : 9999
    min : -6.670651
    max : 7.082235
```

To address this problem, it's possible to use the \r separator. It works well but it put the bunch of statistics I want to track on the same line. Here is the code :

```
i=1
min=99
max=-99
while(i<10000) {
  x=rnorm( 1, 0, 2 )
  if (x<min)min=x
  if (x>max)max=x
  cat("\riteration :",i, "min : ",min, "max : ", max)
  i=i+1
}
```

console view (almost good)

```
iteration : 7747 (running) min :  -7.173628 (running) max :  7.713919988887 (running)
```

My expected result is that I want to stack the statistics, I want to insert a line break inside the \r separator, like this :

```
iteration : 4512 (running)
min : -2.315584 (running)
max : 3.215478 (running)
```

When I add "\r" and "\n" separator in my code like this :

```
i=1
min=99
max=-99
while(i<10000) {
  x=rnorm( 1, 0, 2 )
  if (x<min)min=x
  if (x>max)max=x
  cat("\riteration :",i, "\nmin : ",min, "\nmax : ", max)
  i=i+1
}
```

It doesn't produce the expected result, at each iteration there is a line break!

```
...
min :  -8.344142 
iteration : 9997 
min :  -8.344142 
iteration : 9998 
min :  -8.344142 
iteration : 9999 
min :  -8.344142 
max :  7.99123
```

For each iteration, it writes two lines in the console. My problem is that I want my code to produce only two lines for the whole loop but I want those lines be refreshed with the good values. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try `cat('\r',format(Sys.time(),'%H:%M:%S'), "\n")`

Comment: Thank you but it add a line break at each iteration. NoT what I want.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
cat(format(Sys.time(),'%H:%M:%S'), '\nHi People')
23:34:46 
Hi People
```

When using a `while` loop, R will test the condition and loop through the function until it is either no longer satisfied or a break point condition is included. Your loop as written will run indefinitely.

**Update**

With your new data the problem is clearer. I don't think it is possible. You may have to stick with the one line.

The reason is because after each call of `cat()` the evaluator will stop and get ready for the next operation.

I will demonstrate by using a star `*` to indicate where the line position is at the beginning of the function, and a dollar sign `$` for where it is at the end of the function call.

```
cat(1)
*1$

cat(1, "\n")
*1
$

cat(1, "\r")
^1
```

I had to use a new character to show that it started and ended at the same spot.

Now to why I think it isn't feasible to have the multiple lines with the return:

```
cat(1, "\n", 2, "\r")
*1
$2
```

The carriage return can only go back to the beginning of the last line printed. Once the new line character is used `"\n"`, it is like that first line is a distant memory to the printing method. You are trying to jump back up to the top to change the value of the first line. There is no method to access that first line anymore. It's kind of like going back in time, it's impossible to my knowledge.

One way to sort of get there is to use the form feed `"\f"`. It will act as a "new page" effect. But it will print and erase over and over. It will give you multiple lines but will also produce a flicker effect.

```
for(i in 1:10000) {
  cat("\fOpening Message", i, "\n\nSecond line", i+10)
}
```

Comment: Yeah I knew that but using R studio, it's easy to stop it. I re-formulate my problem. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: It's clearer. But I think you should stick with the one line output. I left an explanation of why I think it isn't possible in the R console. Maybe someone else knows a way.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pierre! for the big explanation you left. Very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Not positive on exactly what you want to accomplish (i.e. I don't see why you need a carriage return or '\r'), but this should give you your desired output:

```
while(1) {
  cat(format(Sys.time(), "%H:%M:%S"))
  cat(" (running of course)")
  cat("\nHi People\n")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't produce the good results. Actually I want that at each iteration, R overwrite the previous output in the console so that it doesn't produce multiple lines but only the number of lines necessary to track mys statistics (three in the example). I reformulate my problem so if you can read it again, it would be nice of you!!! Your code produce : 10,000 lines in the console. I just want it to produce three. Only the values have to be overwritten. Sorry for my english.